# Package migrations not working (no errors)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, composer-php

So, I have created a new package that sites in `vendor/vendorname/package`

I have added the new package to my `app/config/app.php` file's provider array:

```
'Seriousjelly\Portfolio\PortfolioServiceProvider'
```

My package composer.json file seems legit:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src/migrations",
        "src/controllers",
        "src/models",
        "src/repositories"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "Seriousjelly\\Portfolio\\": "src/"
    }
```

And in `seriousjelly/porfolio/src/migrations` I have 2 migrations:

**2014_06_25_060429_create_portfolio_categories_table.php:**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePortfolioCategoriesTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('portfolio_categories', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title', 255);
        $table->string('subtitle', 255);
        $table->string('short_description', 500);
        $table->string('description');
        $table->string('slug', 60);
        $table->timestamp();
    });

    Schema::create('portfolio_item_categories', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('portfolio_categories');
        $table->integer('item_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('portfolio_items');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('portfolio_categories');
    Schema::drop('portfolio_item_categories');
}
}
```

and **2014_06_25_060414_create_portfolio_items_table.php:**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePortfolioItemsTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('portfolio_items', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title', 255);
        $table->string('subtitle', 255)->nullable;
        $table->string('short_description', 500)->nullable;
        $table->string('description', 500);
        $table->string('slug', 60);
        $table->timestamp();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('portfolio_items');
}
}
```

Now, when I run `php artisan migrate --package=seriousjelly/portfolio`

It comes up saying that the migration ran successfully, however, if I check the database only the migrations table has been populated.

If I run the command once more, nothing happens, no errors, no message, nothing.

Any ideas?

p.s other package migrations are the same and seem to run ok, I have attempted composer update and composer dump-autoload but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, ok my bad. It seems that I have incorrectly spelt, turns out it's plural:

```
$table->timestamps();
```

Im not sure why terminal never threw an error though...